# Getting published: writing a book chapter in linguistics

Tags: publications, books, linguistics

I am an assistant professor of linguistics. In order to get promoted to the associate professorship one of the things I need to do is write a book or a book chapter. I was wondering how I could write a chapter in a book to be published. Where should I start? Who do I get in touch with?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my discipline in the social sciences, book chapters are typical outcomes of workshops or of (repeated) conference panels. The book editors usually organize the workshop, which includes funding, establishing contacts and sending out invitations or an open call for papers. As a participant (rather than organizer), it is difficult to know from the outset whether the workshop will result in any form of collective publication, but sometimes the intention to work on a publication is specifically advertised. As an organizer, this is in your hands; and it of course leads to several follow-up questions (how to edit a book etc.) that are beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to interact with other researchers in your field is to be the **editor** of a book. Perhaps there is an existing series of monographs in your research area. If so, you could contact that person with the idea for a research volume which would encompass your field of research. You could then provide one of the chapters (in addition to an introductory chapter!), and you'd have the opportunity to invite others from your discipline to contribute chapters as well.